# Spring Application Context Import

Tags: spring, import, applicationcontext

I have a Project A (Spring Web) and would like to import into another project such as

1. Web Project
2. Desktop Project

How to do it ? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: better to make .jar file of desktop project and import the same into Spring web project. I already did the same for one of my project.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot import "projects" as such. You can make a JAR available as a dependency for a project and then import Spring configurations (i.e. application context) from the JAR into Spring configurations of your project.

**Example**

Project A compiled into `a.jar` with `a-context.xml` in the root folder of `a.jar`. Then in `project-context.xml` in your project you place

```
<import resource="classpath:a-context.xml" />
```

**Your case**

In your case this does not make much sense. I assume the web project is compiled into a `WAR` file? Then you have lots of dependencies that are superfluous if used in a desktop application. Hence, you should extract a common project that is compiled into `common.jar` which can be used as a dependency from both projects.

Comment: I usually split the XML files into layers, so that parts can be reused. Ie Model.xml Daos.xml

Comment: Yes, of course one should generally split more than just "common" but for the purpose of this illustration it should be sufficient. Once the OP gets this concept right refining further should be easy.